# Disappearing ReasonPhrase in C# 7.3, Visual Studio 17.5.4

Tags: visual-studio, api, debugging, visual-studio-2022

In this image you can see I've sent a request message to a remote API server and a response object has been received.  In the debugger, it even shows the ReasonPhrase in the response message.  However, if I hover over that response variable, the ReasonPhrase shows as empty.  Anyone know where it went?

[image]

Comment: It's empty in both places. Look at your image closely.

Comment: Well... I kind of see your point as the curly braces are a different color (white) than the text in the "Here it is" box (orange).  But I suppose that begs the question of where the orange text in the "Here it is" box is coming from.  What is the debugger showing me there?  It doesn't seem to be the current content of the response variable.

Comment: Hi Glenn, any update of this issue? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aluan mentioned, both of the ReasonPhrase are empty string:

[image]

And the orange text comes from the Class structure of your response.

Comment: Actually they are both the empty string. Neither are `null`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry, typo, fixed. Yes, they are both "". :)

Comment: Thanks so much, guys.  The two single tick marks tricked me into thinking it was an opening quotation mark.